# How to allow the user to click on a droppable div such that the other div's dropping functionality should be disabled after clicking a droppable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, droppable

I am very new to jquery. Presently i am working on a project of shopping cart where there are three types of items(item1,item2,item3) and three bags(bag1,bag2,bag3) and one shopping cart such as bag1 accepts item1,item2,item3 , bag2 accepts item2,item3 and bag3 accepts only item3 on drop which I have developed so far.

Now i want to add additional functionality such as the user should first select(click) any one of the bag(example bag1) and then try dropping items into the bag1 such that other two bags dropping functionality should be disable(other bags should not accept any item even if it is acceptable by that bag) and also reverse if user selects other bag.

please try it.I really need help.

**http://jsfiddle.net/Vwu37/15/**

html

```
<div class="bag1" ><p>bag1</p></div>
<div class="bag2" > <p>bag2</p></div>
<div class="bag3" ><p>bag3</p></div>
<div class="item1"><p>item1_1</p></div>
<div class="item1"><p>item2_1</p></div>
<div class="item1"><p>item2_1</p></div>
```

js

```
$('.bag1').droppable({
                accept: '.item1,.item2,.item3',
                 onDragEnter:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='auto';
                },
                onDragLeave:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='not-allowed';
                },
                onDrop:function(e,source){
                    var name = $(source).find('p:eq(0)').html();
                    var price = $(source).find('p:eq(1)').html();
                    addProduct(name, parseFloat(price.split('$')[1]));
                }
            });

            $('.bag2').droppable({
                accept: '.item2,.item3',
                onDragEnter:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='auto';
                },
                onDragLeave:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='not-allowed';
                },
                onDrop:function(e,source){
                    var name = $(source).find('p:eq(0)').html();
                    var price = $(source).find('p:eq(1)').html();
                   }
            });

            $('.bag3').droppable({
                accept: '.item3',
                onDragEnter:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='auto';
                },
                onDragLeave:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='not-allowed';
                },
                onDrop:function(e,source){
                    var name = $(source).find('p:eq(0)').html();
                    var price = $(source).find('p:eq(1)').html();
                                    }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here`s a very simple way to do it for bag1: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yaroslavya/Vwu37/16/)
Note, that, currently I just did:

`$('.bag1').click(function(){`
`//disabling other droppables here`
`});`

You may need to remove this hardcode and write a more generic method to disable your bags. 
I`d suggest you go through [draggable](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [droppable](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable) jquery.ui api methods and find the one most appropriate for your needs. As you may prevent dropping right at the drop moment by checking what drag item and drop bag was used.

Update:
At start drop bags are all disabled [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yaroslavya/Vwu37/18/). If you click any of them it will become enabled and droppable again.

Comment: i actually want the user to  first click any one of the bag they like(either bag1 or bag2 or bag3) then allow them to drop items in that bag itself.Before selecting any one of the bag they should'nt be able to drop any items to it.

Comment: Then you can make the following: 
1.disable all droppables
2. On click add enable the clicked droppable. 
3. Depending on your flow disable droppable after something was dragged into or keep it droppable after click.

Comment: great!!!this is idea is so good!!thanks a lot!!but with this remove button is not working.Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: i noticed one more thing if we click on bag2 and then try dropping item2(which is an acceptable item)its working fine but at the same time when we are dropping item1 or item2 or item3 in bag1 ,bag1 is accepting them which should not happen .Is any way in your view?

Comment: It seems like there`s too much code for now. Please, reduce the amount of code, so that it was convenient to go through it and make changes. Consider fixing errors in console as well.

Comment: yes the code is massive.but if i try to reduce it either of the things is not working.plz if  u have time check whats wrong i am unable to figure it out.i know its not difficult for u as you are a great developer.

Comment: i have reduced the code for u.Every thing is working fine when the user clicks on a bag and try dropping items to it ,it is accepting only those items it should accept and if they try dropping on other non selected bags its not accepting.But this code is also working before the user selects a bag which should not happen.Now your code applies    1.disable all droppables 2. On click add enable the clicked droppable.i tried but not able to execute it right.could u plz try it.plz help me i am really struggling a lot. i need your help.plz plz help me.link to jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/Vwu37/36/

Comment: Check this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yaroslavya/Vwu37/42/
I've updated the code, but it still need to be simplified and improved.

Comment: please help me for my another question . this is your code  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885035/unable-to-display-a-field-in-shopping-cart-using-jquery

Comment: yaroslav please answer my question...i am waiting for your answer since many days......... i badly need help...plz do help me... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885035/unable-to-display-a-field-in-shopping-cart-using-jquery

Comment: yaroslav please answer my question .....please every day i am seeing your profile to see "last seen" please answer my question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885035/unable-to-display-a-field-in-shopping-cart-using-jquery